# Where to find samples about Charts.Net and How to use it?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I’m very interesting to the Charts.Net related components. Do you know where to find some samples about it? Is it possible to use it in our ocean plug-in and handle with our customer domainObject.

Answer (score 1):

There are some GeoToolkit resources located on the Ocean website that might be useful:
http://www.ocean.slb.com/Secure/developers-geotoolkit-resources.aspx

If you have problems with the direct link, go to the Ocean portal and click on "Developers."  In the bottom-right, under "Ocean Developer Resources" you should see a link for "GeoToolkit Resources."

(Note that you need an Ocean Store login to access these resources.)

You can also find a high-level overview of Charts.NET toolkit on the INT website:
http://www.int.com/products/2d/carnacnet/chartcomponent_net.htm